# What do the icons in Internet Explorers status bar mean?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet

Please check the two icons in the red box in the image below. Can anyone tell me what they are for and how to make them go away?

[image]

Comment: what version of IE are you using?

Comment: I am using IE 8.

Answer (score 1):

The first icon is your popup blocker. The second icon (the gear ) is your toolbars and extensions icon.

If you want them to go away, turn off your popup blocker and disable your extensions.

For what its worth, a stock install of IE8 on windows XP does not show those icons.